# stop and then reload the execution of function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to use a function that works like this:

- it will stop the execution of function after executing one time
- after that stop for 10 sec
- then again start execution from that left position.

Can you help me to find the solution of that problem?

Comment: It's almost impossible to tell what you're asking.  Can you provide an example of how you want this to work?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, because JavaScript it executes all in once.. unless they are function that will be call after in the DOM.. so have you tried setTimeout to repeat the same function over and over ?

Comment: Do you mean like `sleep` or should that happen based on an event, like a mouse click?

Comment: Use setTimeout.Refer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418406/stop-and-then-reload-the-execution-of-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can set Timing Events in javascript

It's very easy to time events in JavaScript. The two key methods that are used are:

setInterval() - executes a function, over and over again, at specified time intervals
setTimeout() - executes a function, once, after waiting a specified number of milliseconds

The setInterval() Method
Syntax

```
window.setInterval("javascript function",milliseconds);
```

Example

```
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);

function myTimer()
{
var d=new Date();
var t=d.toLocaleTimeString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `return` and [Window.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout).

```
// The code will have to be told to restart, or not
var restart = true;

function exampleFunction()
{
    if (restart) {
        alert("Restarting function");

        // Start function again in 10 000 milliseconds.
        setTimeout(exampleFunction, 10000);

        // Tell function not to interrupt next time.
        restart = false;

        // Exit early.
        return;
    }

    alert("Function finished");
}

// Start the function
exampleFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a `function a()` in which you want to do certain functionalities, then stop for some reason, and continue.

**First Scenario: Continue after set amount of time**

```
function a() {
  // do stuff
  // time to stop executing has come
  setTimeout("b()", 10000);
}

function b() {
  // this function does what you wanted to continue doing after 10 seconds.
}
```

**Second Scenario: Continue after user event**

```
var hasFiredEvent = false;

function a() {
  // do stuff
  // time to stop executing, until the user fires an event.
  setTimeout("b()", 500);
} 

function b() {
  if (!hasFiredEvent) {
    setTimeout("b()", 500);
  }
  else {
    // do the rest of the code you wanted.
  }
}

// some other code is required to set hasFiredEvent = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**setInterval** function is use to you and find example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CallTimer() {
        alert('test');
    }

    window.onload = startInterval;
    function startInterval() {
        CallTimer();
        setInterval(CallTimer, 100);
    }
</script>
```